# Google Maps Javascript Api Bring Circle to Front

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I'm working with the javascript google maps api and have written a program that draws multiple circles on the map of different colors. The problem is, I'm unsure how to control which ones come to the front. I could do this if it was just regular divs, but I don't know how to control it using the google maps API. Could anyone help out?

Comment: Why would you want to use a convoluted method if you could do it using regular divs?

Answer (score 2):

if you have used circle   you can control the zIndex

```
   var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  center: citymap[city].center,
  radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100,
 zIndex: 200
});
```

The element with greater zIndex is placed on top of the others